# How to add whitespace around character?

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that will add a space before and after the character with php:

> /

It should not match if the string is a number.

E.g.

match: text/second
but not: 001/303030

Unfortunately my regex know how is limited. How could this be done?

Comment: Look, the answer below assumes only the `/` in between letters should be replaced with " / ". Is it what you need? Not the one that is not enclosed with digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following regex in order to match your string:

```
"([a-zA-Z]+)(/)([a-zA-Z]+)"
```

And replace the captured group using a back reference:

```
"\1 \2 \3"
```

You can use `preg_replace` function to that aim.